# sparql use subquery as result/variable for outer query

Tags: sparql

I want to use result of nested query as a variable/sub graph for outer query.
My use-case is I have One-to-Many relation between product and offers, and I want to get all/selected products as well as offers count, minPrice and condition from offer record.
Here is my query

```
SELECT ?ProductID ?priceMIN ?total ?condition
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?ProductID (COUNT(?cond) AS ?total) (MIN(?pr) AS ?priceMIN )  ?condition WHERE{
      ?ProductID ^mod:isOfferOf ?oid.
      ?oid dprop:priceMIN ?pr. 
      ?oid dprop:total ?cond.
      BIND (if( ?cond = 1, "New", "Used") AS ?condition).
    }
  }
  VALUES ?ProductID { prod:Rl5RVl5R prod:Rl5RVl5Q prod:Rl5RVl5W prod:Rl5RVl5Y prod:Rl5RVl5U }
}
```

and i am getting this data.

```
   ProductID      |priceMIN |condition |total
product:Rl5RVl5R  | 3267    |  Used    | 1
product:Rl5RVl5R  | 3216    |  New     | 4
product:Rl5RVl5Y  | 327     |  New     | 1
product:Rl5RVl5Q  | 323     |  New     | 1
product:Rl5RVl5Q  | 3268    |  Used    | 1
product:Rl5RVl5W  | 326     |  New     | 1
product:Rl5RVl5W  | 3271    |  Used    | 4
product:Rl5RVl5U  | 325     |  New     | 2
product:Rl5RVl5U  | 3270    |  Used    | 1
```

Now I want to assign this value like

```
product:Rl5RVl5U dprop:newTotal ?total
product:Rl5RVl5U dprop:newMin ?priceMIN
product:Rl5RVl5U dprop:usedTotal ?total
product:Rl5RVl5U dprop:usedMin ?priceMIN
```

Comment: Same as http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/32850/sparql-use-subquery-as-resultvariable-for-outer-query

Comment: Hi @AndyS But both questions are unanswered .... Can you please help me to make this query ? Thank you...